# How to Unset Key from Session Array PHP

Tags: php

On the front end of my website, a person can add numerous products to their cart.
The products are added to their cart, in the form of a `$_POST['product_id']`, posted to the user's `$_SESSION`.

Should a user wish to remove the item from their cart, I wish to unset the product_id from their session.

However the below, on the `unset` throws a series of fatal errors.

1. `Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings`
2. `Uncaught Error: Cannot unset string offsets in`

Based on looking through previous threads, it looks like I need to use something along the lines of str_replace, but if a product has an ID of "23", and another has a product ID of "423", wouldn't this remove all occurences of 23 and cause problems?

If anyone can point me in the direction of unsetting specific item in the array that would be apprecaited. Thankyou

```
  $response_data = 0;
        if($_POST['product_id']){
                $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
                  if (($key = array_search($product_id, $_SESSION['selected_products'])) !== false) {
                    unset( $_SESSION['selected_products'][$key] );
                }
        }
        $response_data = sizeof($_SESSION['selected_products']);
        echo $response_data;
```

Comment: Make `$_SESSION['selected_products']` an array, not a string…!?

Comment: What are the contents if you `var_dump` `$_SESSION['selected_products']`?